# Drawing vector lines over rivers Openlayers 3 with Openstreetmap

Tags: javascript, canvas, vector, openstreetmap, openlayers-3

First of foremost i would like to know if this is possible at all with the combination of these two (OL and OSM) and if it is how can i draw vector line of a said river.

For example , i need to get a river from osm and draw a vector line over the said river , than the drawn line will be modified via a backend service.

See screenshot for example (From the OSM website):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/krCfX.png

I want to do something like this but with a few selected rivers (All of the selected will be highlighted via the vector line).

Similar to this : http://openlayers.org/en/v3.14.2/examples/box-selection.html

But not with boxes , only lines over rivers, and each line will be modified based on the data from the backend for example: River 1 will be red and more bold , River 2 green and less bold and so on.

Thanks in Advance, Lend

Comment: crosspost: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/187205/drawing-vector-lines-over-rivers-openlayers-3-with-openstreetmap